# Angular2 Injecting a service into Class error

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am working on an Angular2 app and I am trying to inject a service into a class. I have searched all around and found that I need to use `ReflectiveInjector` class, but my issue is that I am still getting a no provider error for the `FirebaseRef` portion of that service.

I have been working on this a couple days and no where can I find a solution that solves my problem. One of the answer on here mentioned having to deal with declaring dependancies, but never gave an answer on how to do that. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Stacktrace

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Token FirebaseApp! (ImageUploadService -> Token FirebaseApp)
Error: No provider for Token FirebaseApp! (ImageUploadService -> Token FirebaseApp)
at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:6124:27)
at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59490:16)
at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:59552:16)
at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:82140:19)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:82179:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:82126:25)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByReflectiveDependency (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:82109:21)
at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:82001:36)
at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiateProvider (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:81968:25)
```

image-upload-service

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { FirebaseRef } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class ImageUploadService {

 constructor(@Inject(FirebaseRef) public fb) { }

  uploadFile(file: File): any {
  var storage = this.fb.storage().ref().child("image.png");


  return storage;
}

testService() {
  console.log("service injector worked!!");
}

}
```

FileUploader.ts

```
import { ReflectiveInjector, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { ImageWrap } from './ImageWrap';
import { ImageUploadService } from '../../services/image-upload.service';
import { FirebaseRef, FIREBASE_PROVIDERS } from 'angularfire2';

export class FileUploader {
  private queue:Array<ImageWrap> = [];
  private uploadService:ImageUploadService;

  public constructor() {
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
     {provide: ImageUploadService, useClass: ImageUploadService}
    ]);
    this.uploadService = injector.resolveAndInstantiate([ImageUploadService]);
  }

  public addToQueue(files:File[]) {
    for(let file of files) {
     let tempName = file.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
     this.queue.push(new ImageWrap(file, tempName));
    }
   for( let image of this.queue) {
     console.log("image name " + image.name);
   }
    // this.uploadService.testService();

  }

  public uploadFile(file:ImageWrap) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `service` to the component is old `syntax`. You no longer add a **provider** inside the **component**.

But you do need to add a `decorator` to the `component` and the `provider` to the correct place which is in **app.module.ts**

inside the `component` should look like this,

```
@Component({
        templateUrl: './path/to/file-uploader.component.html'
    })

export class FileUploader { ...
```

If you do not want to give that file it's own `html` file, then you can add the `html` directly in the `template paramater`. That would look like this,

```
  @Component({
             template: `
                    <h2> This goes in here. It is important to format this correctly having the ticks on the top and bottom line.</h2>
                    `
        })

    export class FileUploader { ...
```

Then you have to add the new `service` you created to the `providers` `array`. You can do this inside of **app.module.ts**

**Example**

// Import Service file

```
import { NameOfServiceExport } from './services/PATH/TO/SERVICE/SERVICE_NAME_HERE.service';
```

// Add the service to the providers array

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PublicComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        SERVICE_NAME_HERE,

    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: This is not a component, it is just a standard class.

Comment: In the answer above he suggested you put a @Component inside of it. So I was clarifying how that works now with the new syntax and that you do not register a provider that way anymore. But the answer to your question should be in my answer. Read the rest of it where it explains how to register a service as a provider now in app.module.ts.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing `@Component` decorator in "FileUploader.ts"

```
import { ReflectiveInjector, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { ImageWrap } from './ImageWrap';
import { ImageUploadService } from '../../services/image-upload.service';
import { FirebaseRef, FIREBASE_PROVIDERS } from 'angularfire2';


@Component({
        selector: 'file-uploader',
        templateUrl: "your template here",
        styleUrls: "your css file here",
        providers: [FIREBASE_PROVIDERS] // <== you need to add firebase provider here.
    })

export class FileUploader {
  private queue:Array<ImageWrap> = [];
  private uploadService:ImageUploadService;

  public constructor() {
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
     {provide: ImageUploadService, useClass: ImageUploadService}
    ]);
    this.uploadService = injector.resolveAndInstantiate([ImageUploadService]);
  }

  public addToQueue(files:File[]) {
    for(let file of files) {
     let tempName = file.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
     this.queue.push(new ImageWrap(file, tempName));
    }
   for( let image of this.queue) {
     console.log("image name " + image.name);
   }
    // this.uploadService.testService();

  }

  public uploadFile(file:ImageWrap) {

  }
}
```

Comment: This is not a component, it is just a standard class.